# Pywin32 generated msg with html content opens in outlook as plain text

Tags: python, outlook, office365, pywin32, msg

I had a working code which generates with predefined html content msg files based on a list. Then our operator clicking on the msg files and manually add the recipients and send the email. This was working I guess, until an office update happened in last December or this year January. The current behavior is that opening the generated msg file will open as plain text.

I read similar issues on the Microsofts forum page:

[link1](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/msg-files-open-as-plain-text-without-html-elements/b8946f21-edde-4929-9996-fd5db68a9a2c)

[link2](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/why-do-i-lose-html-properties-when-saving-email/0ec22c79-dc0d-41e0-ac9e-8f16333670d8)

However these looks like have been fixed as if I manually save email to msg file and reopen it, outlook will opens it in html view.
I can only think something changed in outlook msg export/save which is not introduced in pywin32. Has anyone facing the same issue? Is there any workaround in this matter?

Version of Python (3.12.2) and pywin32 (306)